# How do I search for Haskell packages using "nix search"?

Tags: haskell, nix, nix-flake

I know that I can search for Haskell packages with nix-env by using

```
nix-env -f '<nixpkgs>' -qaP -A haskellPackages name_of_package
```

but that is slow and uncached. If I try to use the new command `nix search` all the Haskell packages are hidden.

```
$ nix search aeson
error: no results for the given search term(s)!
```

Is it possible to search for Haskell packages using the new `nix search` command? If so, how?

---

**Edit:** I found some discussion about this in [this](https://logs.nix.samueldr.com/nixos/2019-01-09) irc log, but I couldn't quite grasp what the suggestions would mean in practice. Specifically this part:

```
20:49 <duairc> How do I make nix search include haskellPackages?
20:52 <ottidmes> duairc: you might try and call recurseIntoAttrs on haskellPackages
20:52 <rain1> thanks
20:52 <LnL> rain1: nix-env -f '<nixpkgs>' -qaP -A haskellPackages
20:54 <gchristensen> duairc: ^
20:54 <duairc> LnL: Thanks!
20:55 <LnL> err, wrong person
20:56 <LnL> you can also add an overlay that recurses, but that might make it
      hard to find non haskell stuff if you're searching for something else
20:56 <ottidmes> I can confirm that
      haskellPackages = super.recurseIntoAttrs super.haskellPackages; works though
20:58 <duairc> ottidmes: What do I do with that expression? Put it in
      configuration.nix somewhere? If I type "nix search ghcid" then
      will it find it?
20:59 <duairc> Ah, you're using super, so I guess it's an overlay
20:59 <clever> duairc: for `nix search` to find it, the overlay must be
      somewhere in $HOME, i forget the exact path
20:59 <clever> duairc: configuration.nix only effects nixos-rebuild and
      nothing else
21:00 <ottidmes> duairc: yeah, it should be put in your overlay that is
      also used by nix-env the like, so not nixpkgs.overlays in your
      configuration.nix as mentioned by clever, and then searching
      for e.g. nix search nix-diff will result in:
      * nixpkgs.haskellPackages.nix-diff (nix-diff)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the IRC chat, create a `~/.config/nixpkgs/overlays.nix` file containing this:

```nix
[
  (self: super: {
    haskellPackages = super.recurseIntoAttrs super.haskellPackages;
  })
]
```

This is an overlay that sets the `recurseForDerivations` attribute of the haskellPackages set to true. `recurseForDerivations` tells nix tools to traverse the set, which searches it in the case of `nix search`. It is currently undocumented, but implemented [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/d5ecb8d3cd8cb2ae63966025c914fd4beff0a6ea/src/libexpr/get-drvs.cc#L346-L355).

The [Nix wiki](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Overlays#On_the_user_level) describes where to put the overlay and the [Nixpkgs manual](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-overlays-definition) describes what overlays actually are and how to use them.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this looks like exactly what I need. For it to work however, I needed to put it after any other overlays that modifies `haskellPackages`. Not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

You could save the result of this:

```
nix-env -f '<nixpkgs>' -qaP -A haskellPackages
```

And search that output each time instead?

I think the issue is `<nixpkgs>` will have to be evaluated at each invocation, however if this was a static file/path - it would not need to be.

Comment: Yes, this is an improvement. However, I had hoped that it was possible to use the new fancy `nix search` command for it and from the IRC log I linked, I got the impression that it was possible. I just don't understand how.

Answer (score 1):

To search the latest on GitHub `NixOS/nixpkgs`:

```
nix search nixpkgs#haskellPackages PACKAGE_NAME
```

i.e.

```
nix search nixpkgs#haskellPackages aeson
```

will yield

```
* legacyPackages.x86_64-linux.haskellPackages.AesonBson (0.4.1)
  Mapping between Aeson's JSON and Bson objects

* legacyPackages.x86_64-linux.haskellPackages.HsYAML-aeson (0.2.0.1)
  JSON to YAML Adapter

* legacyPackages.x86_64-linux.haskellPackages.Quickson (0.2)
  Quick JSON extractions with Aeson

* legacyPackages.x86_64-linux.haskellPackages.abeson (0.1.0.1)
  interconversion between aeson and bson

* legacyPackages.x86_64-linux.haskellPackages.activitystreams-aeson (0.2.0.2)
  An interface to the ActivityStreams specification

* legacyPackages.x86_64-linux.haskellPackages.aeson (2.1.2.1)
  Fast JSON parsing and encoding

.
.
.
```

Another example

```
$ nix search nixpkgs#haskellPackages aeson_2  
       
* legacyPackages.x86_64-linux.haskellPackages.aeson_2_2_0_0 (2.2.0.0)
  Fast JSON parsing and encoding
```

---

If you have checked out `nixpkgs` locally, it would be:

```
nix search .#haskellPackages aeson
```